# div grid which dynamically rescales

Tags: css

I'd like to get the following layout:

```
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

where each `[ ]` should be at most 300x150px, but scale down to the
bounding box as needed, conserving aspect ratio.

```
.field {
    width: 16%;
}

.field .placeholder{
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

I tried adding a placeholder div inside the divs, but that didn't
really help, it gives me something akin to

```
[ ]
[ ]
[ ]
...
```

Comment: This looks very much like a table. Are you sure it's not a table?

Comment: what's the purpose of this structure?

Comment: @F.Calderan it should serve as a playing field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a table is what I need.

```
td { width: 1%; }
```

takes care of equal horizontally, but I still have the problem of vertical spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using max-width and max-height css properties, and set width and height to some percents.

Comment: That still gives me a `[]\n[]\n` layout.

Comment: Can you provide more code? html structure and css ? Maybe a jsFiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

Is it something are you looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/codef0rmer/mNkEj/